# variable changes unexpectedly in For loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am experiencing a really weird problem with my VBA code.

Although I can tell why it is not working but I can't fix the problem.

```
'ws is the worksheet object I have created during run time. 
ws.Range("A1:AAA9000").Clear
ws.Activate
ws.Select 

'Covariance Matrix

Range("A1").Value = "Covariance Matrix"

For i = 1 To num_assets
    For j = 1 To num_assets

        MsgBox "i = " & i & ", j=" & j
        Cells(1 + i, 1 + j).Value = Covariance(i, j)
    Next j
Next I
```

Here is my analysis so far.

Case 1. This code is working fine if the Covariance matrix is filled to the cells in the existing worksheet created before the run time.

Case 2. This code is behaving really strange if applied to the cells in the new worksheet dynamically created during the run time.

In the for loop, `i` starts with 1 then `i` suddenly jumps to 145. Excel throws `Subscript out of range` error because the Covariance matrix is just 4 x 4 matrix. and the code gets terminated.

The "Covariance Matrix" header is written to cell `A1` without any problem. The similar problem is keep appearing whenever I used for loop to fill some range with some values from array or matrix.

None of the problem happens if I apply the entire code to the existing worksheet created before running the VBA code.

So the conclusion is that it is caused by using the new worksheet dynamically created during the run time. But how can I fix this code to run safely in the new worksheet created during run time ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

================================================================

After I received few questions, I decided to include how the variable are defined.

```
Public Covariance() As Double
Public i, j, k As Integer
Public num_assets, num_periods As Integer
```

=================================================================

This is another part to show how the num_assets are assigned. When I print the num_assets and num_periods they were perfectly correct.

```
num_assets = dataRange.Columns.Count
num_periods = dataRange.Rows.Count

ReDim Covariance(num_assets, num_assets) As Double

MsgBox "Num Assets " & num_assets & ", Num Periods " & num_periods
```

Comment: If `Covariance` an array or a function?

Comment: You should explain what are you trying to do, also the title is misleading.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding `Select` and properly qualifying your range and cell calls using the `ws` variable

Comment: Also, if you just created `ws` during runtime, why are you clearing the sheet?

Comment: Covariance is array with 2 dimension (i.e. matrix)

Comment: Surely ws.select  don't need to be there. But I added to see if it helps for the problem.

Comment: As someone mentioned, this code block is not necessary ws.Range("A1:AAA9000").Clear

Comment: The funny things is that i in For loop start with 1 but in next iteration, it jump to 145.

Comment: There has got to be something you are not telling us. Are these two lines really the only ones inside the loop? Does `i` jump to 145 after the `Next j` or `Next i`? Please include a sample definition of `Covariance` and make sure the code produces the same behaviour in its reduced version. Also include variable declarations (`Dim .. As ..`)

Comment: The obvious next step is the variable `num_assets`. Where and how is it declared & filled?

Comment: arcadeprecinct : yes, there are only two code lines inside. i inside For loop jump to 145 after next j. For example, it start with i=1, j =1, then it jump to i =145, j =2.

Comment: variable changes unexpectedly in For loop. Good title though. I like it and I like this community. :)

Comment: I double confirmed that num_assets is assigned correctly again. As the code line works perfectly when these code line are applied to exsiting worksheet created before the run time. I tried to place with with Sheets(ws.Index) and end With. but still this does not fix the solution. Just for your information.

Comment: @auto9817 (this is how you address specific users so they get a notification, you always get notifications because it's your post). What happens if you comment out the line `Cells(1 + i, 1 + j).Value = ...`? (i.e. is it because the new sheet is active or has it something to do with that line). What happens if you use `ws.Cells(...)`? Is the new worksheet in the same workbook as the macro? Also can you combine your code snippets so it's clearer what happens when and where? For example are the variable declared inside the sub/function or outside (making them global)?

Comment: Another question: is there anything significant to the value 145? Like is it the value of `num_assets` or the number of used rows in your sheet?

Comment: I just saw you have declared the variables `Public`. This is most likely the problem. I'll write an answer explaining more.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I see two ways this could happen (I include the second although that's not the solution in this case because it could help someone experiencing a similar problem)

1. You have `i` declared globally (outside of the sub/function) and are changing it somehow. In this case the only way I see that happening would be if you have a worksheet event that gets triggered and does something with `i` itself. For example if you had something like

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       For i = 1 To 144
           'dosomething
       Next i
   End Sub
   ```

   that would cause the value of `i` to jump to 145. The solution is, of course, to declare all variables locally unless you really, really need them to be global.
2. You have a sub or function that changes `i`. Note that if you pass `i` as an argument to a function that function can change i by default. If you don't want that, declare the function like this:

   ```
   Public Function Covariance(ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long) As ...
   ```

   That way only the value, not the variable itself is passed to the function. Btw, it won't make a difference if you name the arguments of the function differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to do something based on your advice. I really hope that it will fix the problem. Thanks so much so far for your help. :) I will let you know how it goes pretty soon.

Comment: Your reasoning worked perfectly. thanks so much for your help. It was really fixed with using local variable.